# R join data efficiently if one of the columns in the first dataset matches any of the columns in the second dataset

Tags: r, join, left-join

Given 2 dataframes:

df1

```
col1 col2 col3
43    21   "a"
32    31   "b"
NA    12   "c"
44    NA   "d"
```

df2

```
cl4 cl5 cl6
43   1  "text"
12   0  "text2"
32   44  "text3"
```

How can I merge them with a left_join, if one value of the columns in `c("col1", "col2")` matches a value in the columns `c("cl4", "cl5")` ?
Additional information: all variables can have missing values, except cl6 which is always completed.

Expected result:

```
col1 col2 col3 cl4 cl5 cl6
43    21   "a"  43   1 "text"
32    31   "b"  32  44 "text3"
NA    12   "c"  12   0 "text2"
44    NA   "d"  32  44 "text3"
```

I have some code that works, but I think there must be a better solution if there are a lot of joins to be done (in my real dataframes I have 24 joins to do...).
Here is my code:

```
list_vars = c('cl4', "cl5", "cl6")
list_vars_rename = c("col4", "col5", "col6")

#MERGE 1

df1_merged <- left_join(df1, df2, by=c("col1" = "cl4"), na_matches = "never") #ignore NAs

df1_merged$cl4 <- df1_merged$col1 #because cl4 disappears during the join
df1_merged[is.na(df1_merged$cl6), "cl4"] <- NA #cl4 equals NA if no match = if cl6 NA

setnames(df1_merged, old = list_vars, new = list_vars_rename, skip_absent = T) #rename cols

#MERGE 2
df1_merged <- left_join(df1_merged, df2, by=c("col1" = "cl5"), na_matches = "never")
df1_merged <- as.data.frame(df1_merged) #because was a tibble
df1_merged$cl5 <- df1_merged$col1 #because cl4 disappears during the join
df1_merged[is.na(df1_merged$cl6), "cl5"] <- NA #cl5 equals NA if no match = if cl6 NA
for (i in seq_along(list_vars_rename)){
  df1_merged[,list_vars_rename[i]] <- ifelse(is.na(df1_merged[,list_vars_rename[i]]), df1_merged[,list_vars[i]], df1_merged[,list_vars_rename[i]])
} #fill col4, col5 & col6 with the values of cl4, cl5 & cl6 we got in the join
df1_merged = df1_merged[, !(names(df1_merged) %in% list_vars)] #drop cl4 ,cl5 & cl6

#MERGE 3
df1_merged <- left_join(df1_merged, ventes, by=c("col2" = "cl4"), na_matches = "never")
df1_merged <- as.data.frame(df1_merged)
df1_merged$cl4 <- df1_merged$col2
df1_merged[is.na(df1_merged$cl6), "cl4"] <- NA
for (i in seq_along(list_vars_rename)){
  df1_merged[,list_vars_rename[i]] <- ifelse(is.na(df1_merged[,list_vars_rename[i]]), df1_merged[,list_vars[i]], df1_merged[,list_vars_rename[i]])
}
df1_merged= df1_merged[, !(names(df1_merged) %in% list_vars)]

###etc. until the last merge.
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite get there, but maybe this code helps:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- read_table("col1 col2 col3
43    21   a
32    31   b
NA    12   c
44    NA   d")

df2 <- read_table("cl4 cl5 cl6
43   1  text
12   0  text2
32   44  text3")

cols_1 <- c("col1", "col2")
cols_2 <- c("cl4", "cl5")

df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = all_of(cols_1)) %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% pivot_longer(cols = all_of(cols_2)), by = "value", suffix = c(".df1", ".df2")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(name.df1) & !is.na(name.df2))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   col3  name.df1 value cl6   name.df2
#>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>   
#> 1 a     col1        43 text  cl4     
#> 2 b     col1        32 text3 cl4     
#> 3 c     col2        12 text2 cl4     
#> 4 d     col1        44 text3 cl5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

The output contains the columns containing the important info (`col3` and `cl6`), and it tells you what columns matched (`name.df1` and `name.df2`), and what the matching value is (`value`). But I couldn't figure out how to add back the other information to match your desired output. Also I didn't deal with `NA`s.